# Could You Use a Generator to Load Data in Steps in an Angular 2 App?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, angular, typescript, generator

I am using ng2-pagination to handle the display of records in my Angular 2 app, and I am trying to think through a way to handle pulling in a large data set from our mongoDB backend API in steps - so as to reduce the immediate load, and have the initial page load with data faster for the user.

And then I had a thought: is this a situation where one could use an ES6 generator? Then you could call for results from the API in steps. Maybe 100 records initially, then some more, and then the remainder, and the last two steps could happen behind the scenes, while still allowing for a better user experience because the initial call is for a smaller number of records that would allow the front-end page to load relatively quickly.

The data I'm calling is from an array of about 10,000 objects in our mongoDB collection. Seems like a generator could work here because it works with iteration.

Does this seem like a doable option? Is this a valid use-case for a generator?

Comment: I'd say adding 10,000 objects to the DOM is quite a bad idea, especially if they are not all visible at the same time. I'd just use an `Observable` and add the data there and bind the view to the observable. But again, make sure you only add elements to the DOM, the user can actually see. There are enough components that allow virtual scrolling. If none fits, build your own.

Comment: Right. I agree adding 10,000 objects all in one go is a bad idea. That's why I was wondering if a generator could handle it in steps (i.e. chunks). As in, initially load the first 100 objects. Then, after yielding, continue loading in the remaining data in several more chunks. That would be happening AFTER page load, so it wouldn't affect the user experience. And then, once that's been done, cache it.

Comment: It's not only about adding them at once, it's also about adding them at all. If you add another 100, remove the previous 100 so that there are never more then 100 added to the DOM at one point in time. (100 is just a made up number, the lower the better. 1000 would already be way better than 10000)

Comment: Have a link to that kind of implementation, Gunter? By the way, did some more searching, and this article seems to be describing what I was suggesting: using generators to handle this: https://derickbailey.com/2015/11/18/finitely-iterating-infinite-data-with-es6-generators/

Comment: https://www.google.at/search?q=angular2+virtual+scroll&oq=angular2+virtual+scroll&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.5144j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=angular2+material+virtual+scroll&* for angular/material2 it's not yet available https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/823